# How to Use SELECT Query on Xml using java

Tags: java, xml

I am having an xml file which contains data from different tables. 
These tables are linked to each other.

I want to access Records from the xml.

Can i write SQL select query on Xml file.

Comment: which database are you using? What have you tried so far, can you share some code?

Comment: Have you tried [XQJ](http://www.xquery.com/tutorials/xqj_tutorial/)(XQuery for Java) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use SQL for XML files. Either move the data to a relational store or use a hierarchical query language.

All you can expect after such a vague question is a bunch of random keywords (like XQuery, eXist, XPath, Oracle XML Db, MarkLogic, Jaxen). Probably none of them is relevant to whatever problem you might have at hand.